# Ambiguous “it” pronoun

Tags: pronouns, speech

If I said, “losing the race..it is a tragedy...a loss.a shame...if I fell during the race.”

What does the “it” pronoun refer to? Does it refer to - Losing the race? Or the event of me falling during the race?

Comment: It is ambiguous.

Comment: The ellipses make it ambiguous. But most people would probably interpret it as referring to losing the race—an independent clause (*losing the race is a tragedy*)  with a dependent, appositive clause that follows it (*[losing the race is] a loss, a shame, if I fell during it*.)

Comment: thank you, I would take the independent clause to be - losing the race is a tragedy and a loss and a shame - and the dependent clause to be -if I fell during the race-